# How to convert a boolean array to byte and back in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write and read bytes from usb device.
I have an array dout(8) of boolean say f,t,t,f,t,t,f,t representing switch states.
I need to convert that to a variable DataOut as byte. 01101101

Later I read the usb device.
This gives me a variable Data as byte 10110100
I need to convert that to an array DIn(10) of boolean  t,f,t,t,f,t,f,f

All my code attempts have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [System.BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to worry about thinking in binary, there is a class called BitArray that will help you.

Comment: Dim BitString As New BitArray(8)
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim s As String = ""

        For j = 0 To 7
            BitString.Set(j, DOut(j + 1))
        Next

        s = IIf(BitString.Get(0), "1", "0")

        For j = 1 To 7
            s = s + IIf(BitString.Get(j), "1", "0")
        Next

Comment: Dim BitString As New BitArray(8)
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim s As String = ""

  For j = 0 To 7
       BitString.Set(j, DOut(j + 1))
  Next
Now how do I get from here to byte?
        s = IIf(BitString.Get(0), "1", "0")

        For j = 1 To 7
            s = s + IIf(BitString.Get(j), "1", "0")
        Next
        Label7.Text = s